# iPython timeit - only time part of the operation

Tags: python, ipython, timing

I was attempting to determine, via iPython's `%%timeit` mechanism, whether `set.remove` is faster than `list.remove` when a conundrum came up.

I could do

```py
In [1]: %%timeit
a_list = list(range(100))
a_list.remove(50)
```

and then do the same thing but with a `set`.  However, this would include the overhead from the `list`/`set` construction.  Is there a way to re-build the `list`/`set` each iteration but only time the `remove` method?

Comment: I know how to do this with the `timeit.timeit` function, but not with `%%timeit`...

Comment: fwiw, the answer is almost-certainly _yes a set is hugely faster_ for a collection of any meaningful size (both because a hashmap is faster than the linear search and list remove is `O(n)` as it shifts all the following elements) .. you could also time just the creation independently and subtract it off your result (however, if you were _certain_ your list was sorted, https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html might be faster for some collections)

Comment: @ti7 At least for the set, I wouldn't be surprised if fluctuation in the creation time was larger than the removal time. That subtraction might even report a negative time for the removal :-)

Comment: Yeah, the set creation was much longer than the list creation.

Comment: @KellyBundy very likely! (and worse with the size of the set.. hmm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your *setup code* on the same line to create any names or precursor operations you need!
https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit

> In cell mode, the statement in the first line is used as setup code (executed but not timed) and the body of the cell is timed. The cell body has access to any variables created in the setup code.

```py
%%timeit setup_code
...
```

Unfortunately only a single run can be done as it does not re-run the setup code

```py
%%timeit -n1 x = list(range(100))
x.remove(50)
```

Surprisingly, this doesn't accept a string like the `timeit` module, so combined with the single run requirement, I'd still defer to `timeit` with a string `setup=` and repeat it if lots of setup or a statistically higher precision is needed

See [**@Kelly Bundy**'s much more precise answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72706414/4541045) for more!

Comment: @DanielWalker Maybe try it without the speech marks... It might think they are part of the code, in which case `x` will never be defined

Comment: You mean the quotation marks?

Comment: @Lecdi I need to find a box with iPython; `timeit` expects the setup code to be passed as a string, so it's imo reasonable to assume `%%timeit` does too (though I'm not certain)

Comment: Yes, remove the quotes and add `-n1`.

Comment: @KellyBundy wow, that's a surprising design imo, but makes sense (successive runs remove the 50..) updated to include all that - cheers!

Comment: I often use the cell version of `%%timeit` to separate the setup.  Usually I ignore the `n,r` parameters, letting `timeit` choice reasonable values.  This is the first time I recall needing to set `-n1`.  But a larger `-r` can still be used to get a bigger sample.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, using the `timeit` module with more repetitions and some statistics:

```
list: 814 ns ± 3.7 ns
 set: 152 ns ± 1.6 ns
list: 815 ns ± 4.3 ns
 set: 154 ns ± 1.6 ns
list: 817 ns ± 4.3 ns
 set: 153 ns ± 1.6 ns
```

Code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBNasMwEIX3PsVsjCRjgoQbaA0@SQhBqcataPWDNA2U0EP1CrmYKzluobMa3pv55knxk16DHx5jWpY5BQdkHVoC62JIBAkjampWJ5Mmm8k@51/XofZ90Q1emmYOCU5gPSTtX5APYmygVJXfrDfVYe9ln/XAMhK727Uow7Rd4sxo0ruELlyQ76Uo0/OqlZFr5XzxO19JKarrP9wZ06T6jTAp2XV78R9@IOhA4dOahmqUXPKj4ZTFYSwoeTz@bcRkfQnSPuQR2sGAz3D7hnan5tIyaIHXHP36@grYfqC2QizLDw)):

```
from timeit import repeat
from statistics import mean, stdev

for _ in range(3):
    for kind in 'list', 'set':
        ts = repeat('data.remove(50)', f'data = {kind}(range(100))', number=1, repeat=10**5)
        ts = [t * 1e9 for t in sorted(ts)[:1000]]
        print('%4s: %3d ns ± %.1f ns' % (kind, mean(ts), stdev(ts)))
```